# Is it possible to forward a USB port from a Mac to a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, mac, usb

So, I have a Mac mini int the cloud with MacStadium. I want to sideload a app from a app I made onto my iPhone, but I can't physically access the Mac. I control the Mac from a Windows PC using TeamViewer. Is it possible to make the Mac think my PC's ports are it's own, and send the app that I want to sideload via my PC's USB ports?